# Replacing old list with new list java

Tags: java, arraylist

so basically right now I have a list, in order to remove invalid items from the list I'm looping through it and saving all valid items to a new list. After the loop is done I want to set the old list equal to the new list. I'm just wondering, if I go

```
list = newList;
```

will list now be a pointer to newList? Or will I have 2 completely independent lists now.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you just remove the items from the first list and be done with it? Or is this a hypothetical question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will be assigning to `list` a reference to the same list that `newList` references. After the assignment, there will be only one list involved (`list` and `newList` will reference the same object). Also, unless you have another reference to the object that `list` used to reference, the object that `list` used to reference will then be garbage collected.

Following up on the comment by SamV, if the list supports deletion, you don't need two lists for this operation:

```
List<Thing> list = . . .;
for (Iterator<Thing> iter = list.iterator(); iter.hasNext(); ) {
    Thing t = iter.next();
    if (!isValid(t)) {
        iter.remove(); // removal through the iterator itself is ok
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply iterate over that list, then check for validity, if not a valid just remove it.

```
for (Iterator<SomeThing> itr = oldList.iterator(); itr.hasNext();) {
    SomeThing smt = itr.next();

    if(!valid) {
        itr.remove();
    }
 }
```

In this way you don't have to create a new list, then fill it and then assign it to the old one, you will skip all that code.

Answer (score 0):

When you use this `list = newList;` the value of newList, which is the reference to your list with valid items is copied to the list.

So yeah, now list and newList will be referencing to the exactly same object.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider whether mutating the list is necessary.  Removing items from a list that have two variables pointed to it will only add confusion.  Variable are labels and if they are getting assigned in multiple places their meaning changes.  It sounds like you would like to filter the list based on a predicate.  With Java 8 you can do the following.

```
List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("foo", "bar", "baz"));

List<String> wordsStartingWithB = // filtered list
    words.stream()
         .filter(word -> word.toUpperCase().startsWith("B"))
         .collect(Collectors.toList());

wordsStartingWithB.stream()
                  .forEach(s -> System.out.println(s));
// bar
// baz
```

This allow words to remain intact in the original form while the wordsStartingWithB will contain only the items you want.  It also give you the advantage of being able to give the variable a meaningful name since its meaning will not change later on.  Try putting final in front of your variables to see how it causes you to rethink the problem.

The java.util.Stream adds many other useful methods.  You can replace .stream() with parallelStream() when it makes sense to take advantage of running in parallel.

http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html